# Serverless Error: "An Error Occurred: fifo already exsists"

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-sqs, serverless, fifo

I'm trying to deploy with servereless and keep getting " An error occurred: DeadLetterQueueDlq - sms-retry-dlq-v1.fifo already exists." However, sms-retry-dlq-v1.fifo is only called that time. And DeadLetterQueueDlq is only called 1 time as well. Is there anything I need to change within these resources?

```
RetryDeadLetterQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: sms-retry-v1.fifo
    FifoQueue: true
    ContentBasedDeduplication: true
    KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sqs
    VisibilityTimeout: 1000
    RedrivePolicy:
      maxReceiveCount: 7
      deadLetterTargetArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "DeadLetterQueueDlq"
          - "Arn"

DeadLetterQueueDlq:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: sms-retry-dlq-v1.fifo
    FifoQueue: true
    ContentBasedDeduplication: true
    KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sqs
```

Comment: Maybe you've created them in console, or in other stack? Thus you get error about duplicates?

Comment: @Marcin I've created all my sqs in console. However, that's the only sqs that's giving me an issue. Should I not call a resource I create in console?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The queue in question had been creating in console first. Thus you can't create the second one of the same name using CloudFormation (CFN).

Thus, you can either delete the one created in console and re-create it in CFN, or [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) it into CFN.